# Overwrite Material UI prop types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using React, Typescript, and Material UI. I'm using `createMuiTheme.props` to disable ripple for the `ListItem` component globally like this:

```
createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiListItem: {
      disableRipple: true,
      disableTouchRipple: true,
      disableFocusRibble: true
    }
  }
})
```

But Typescript complains that:

> Types of property 'MuiListItem' are incompatible.
> Type '{ disableRipple: boolean; disableTouchRipple: boolean; disableFocusRibble: boolean; }' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<OverrideProps<ListItemTypeMap<{}, "li">, "li">>'.ts(2322)

So I created a `types.d.ts` file in the project root and added the following code:

```
import { ListItemProps as PrevListItemProps } from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import { ButtonBaseProps } from "@material-ui/core/ButtonBase";

declare module "@material-ui/core/ListItem" {
  export type ListItemProps = PrevListItemProps & ButtonBaseProps;
}
```

Which fixes the previous issue but now Typescripts errors because:

> ListItem.d.ts(50, 13): 'ListItemProps' was also declared here.

Any idea how to fix this? Or disable ripple for `ListItem` without passing it each time to components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable ripple effect globally for all buttons:
https://material-ui.com/ru/getting-started/faq/

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiButtonBase: {
      disableRipple: true,       
    },
  },
})
```

Or you can create your own component:

```
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'

const CustomListItem = props => <ListItem {...props} button disableRipple disableTouchRipple />
```